# Vertical align not working inside table column

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 4 cells (2 rows, 2 columns).

Inside every cell I have a table with different heights.

When I display this table I see this:

[image]

But I want them to be vertically on the top of their cell, like this:

[image]

I have tried to add this class to the external table:

```
.externalTable tr td  {
      vertical-align: top;
}
```

or

```
.externalTable  {
      vertical-align: top;
}
```

without success... any ideas?

Comment: you have to post your code and css

Comment: Make sure the **td** has **display: table-cell;**

Comment: With just that line of CSS we can't help. Give us a minimal, reproductible example.

Comment: @sonia - perfect! please convert your comment to an answer, so I can accept. THANKS

Comment: you can try to use margin CSS properties to move inside elements.

Comment: @SpaceDog Done! It was great to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the **td** has below CSS

```
td {display: table-cell;}
```

Comment: THANKS! You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Specify height of the cell and try to give like this.

```
#cellID{
    display: flex;
    height: 50vh; //height of the cell
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```